# Xamarin iOS Universal Links support for Twitter Auth

Tags: ios, twitter, xamarin, uiwebview, ios-universal-links

So, now twitter from 25 sep supports universal linking, it means that when UIWebView hits https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token link, it tries to open a twitter app, and if it is there, then it redirects me to auth page with auth error, so I wonder, how can I disable it from code, without uninstalling twitter app, or how I can enable universal linking auth in my xamarin ios app? Is it possible at all?

(similar question but for native: [Disable Twitter Universal Deep Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824532/disable-twitter-universal-deep-links))

Answer (score 1):

Unless Twitter removes/updates the apps section of "https://www.twitter.com/apple-app-site-association" to allow a bypass or a secondary oauth that is not in the apple-app-site-association file I do not see how you would do it. These files are signed and iOS handles them at an OS level.

I have not played around very much with the continueUserActivity delegate and the NSUserActivity object that is passed to apps launched from UNI links, but I do not see a way for the launched app (i.e. Twitter) to return control to the original app, and at that point the oauth call-chain would be broken anyway....

- Unique. Unlike custom URL schemes, universal links can’t be claimed by other apps, because they use standard HTTP or HTTPS links to your website.
- Secure. When users install your app, iOS checks a file that you’ve uploaded to your web server to make sure that your website allows your app to open URLs on its behalf. Only you can create and upload this file, so the association of your website with your app is secure.

Via: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html