# iOS 9.0.2 Web view Problems in Twitter API

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, xamarin, ios9.1

I  have problem ,in web view when ever i am calling twitter api calls for login , it's opening Twitter app in iOS 9.0.2 instead of opening in webview even after i optout from ATS.

Ref Link1 : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Ref Link2 : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/#Opting-Out-of-ATS

Comment: Post some code you have already tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824532/disable-twitter-universal-deep-links/32926624#32926624 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926216/xamarin-ios-universal-links-support-for-twitter-auth

Comment: Thanks Robert for your reply. i got a right path

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824532/disable-twitter-universal-deep-links/33033836#33033836), there is a work around until twitter fixes it's issue related to security.