# Twitter Oauth v2 API: Disable Universal Link on Mobile

Tags: google-chrome, twitter, twitter-oauth, android-deep-link, twitter-api-v2

I am running into an issue that is much like this one from eight years ago:
[Disable Twitter Universal Deep Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824532/disable-twitter-universal-deep-links)

As this is from 2015, it appears this is not v2.  In my case, I am using v2 and running into the same issue.

My website has an authentication page that redirects to `https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize`

- On desktop this works as expected
- On mobile (Android-tested) without Twitter app installed works as expected
- On mobile (Android-tested) with Twitter app installed the Twitter app attempts to open but shuts down immediately.  **The user therefore cannot log in**.

I did see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33744920/3602057) and tried using the corresponding v2 API call (`https://api.twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize`) but it results in the following error:

```
The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview
```

How do I modify the sign-in process so that a user who has the Twitter app installed on their device can sign into my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW this appears to be a bug with Twitter Droid App:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1466875#c4

I have opened a new issue here:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-with-twitter-droid-app-users-cannot-log-in/201907